# Mysql Replication Master/Slave and Master/Master

Tags: mysql, replication

Looking for some insight and opinions from some DBAs, as I've been tasked to look into using Master/Master replication for a single table in a database.

We currently run mysql replication using a Master/Slave setup for all of our DBs. Is it possible to run Master/Master on a single table within a database while the remaining tables are replicated using Master/Slave? Is this even possible, or just a nightmare?

Another way I've seen it done, is to run 2 different mysql daemons (running on different ports), one using master/master and the other running master/slave. This method though seems like it would require more maintenance. Again, any comments?

Thanks for your help.